# How to Show detail view of table cell inside of table view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitableview

I've a problem. I want to create a table view in which each cell is a name of a place and when the user clicks on the cell, the cell next to it should shift down to accomodate a new view after the clicked cell. The new view will display the address of the place the clicked cell displayed.

for example: 
If cell2 contains XYZ Park.The user clicks on cell2. Now a new view will be displayed after the cell2 & in between cell2 & cell3.This new view will display the address of the XYZ Park.

Please help me &  tell that is this  possible?? :(

Comment: I'd ask on ui.stackexchange if this is a good idea to start with. I would expect it to go to a details view if I selected a cell not INSERT another cell

Comment: I think that if you have many data to display, a detail view is preferable, but for a single line, it could be better to add a detail cell or growing selected cell to display additional data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think that it is possible:

On cell selection, you can add a new cell on the UITableView:

```
– insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

Then, the table view data source will received message:

```
– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

You can return a new cell with the detail (for address).

Be carefull: You have to think about the indexPath of all you cells with a new cell inserted.